# How do you duplicate rows n times by group and change one specific column value in R?

Tags: r, plyr

I am trying to create duplicate rows by group.  The number of duplicate rows I want to create varies by group and I want to fix the value of one column Attended = 0.

A minimal working example of the data set DF I am working with is:

```
ID  Demo  Attended  t
1   3     1         1
1   3     1         3
1   3     0         4
1   3     1         5
2   5     1         2
2   5     1         4
3   7     0         1
```

For the example above, suppose I want every person (ID) to have 5 rows, with Demo the same across all rows for each individual.  Thus, I have to create 1 row for ID = 1, 3 for ID = 2 and 4 for ID = 4 (I would like to calculate these dynamically for each subgroup).  For the new rows I generate I want Attended = 0 and t to take on the value of a missing index, so that the final output is:

```
ID  Demo  Attended  t
1   3     1         1
1   3     1         3
1   3     0         4
1   3     1         5
1   3     0         2
2   5     1         2
2   5     1         4
2   5     0         1
2   5     0         3
2   5     0         5
3   7     0         1
3   7     0         2
3   7     0         3
3   7     0         4
3   7     0         5
```

I have been able to create duplicate rows by group, but haven't been able to figure out how to create different number of duplicates by participant and correctly fill in the index column t.

Here is what I have working:

```
DF %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  rbind(., mutate(., t = row_number()))
```

I have been trying to create the right number of duplicates using `slice()` and trying to get the t value to be exactly what I want but to no avail.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One `tidyverse` possibility could be:

```
df %>%
 complete(t, nesting(ID), fill = list(Attended = 0)) %>%
 arrange(ID)

       t    ID  Demo Attended
   <int> <int> <int>    <dbl>
 1     1     1     3        1
 2     2     1     3        0
 3     3     1     3        1
 4     4     1     3        0
 5     5     1     3        1
 6     1     2     5        0
 7     2     2     5        1
 8     3     2     5        0
 9     4     2     5        1
10     5     2     5        0
11     1     3     7        0
12     2     3     7        0
13     3     3     7        0
14     4     3     7        0
15     5     3     7        0
```

Comment: Hi @tmfmnk thank you for this suggestion.  This would be a very neat solution.  In the data set I have, there are a lot of variables that are equivalent to "Demo".  Listing them all would take a long time.  Thus, in the nesting function, I tried leaving it both empty or setting it to: ```nesting(-t, -Attended)```, this did not work however.  Could you provide some insight on which variables nesting is supposed to capture here?  I just looked at the ```complete()``` function documentation but am not 100% clear.

Comment: I should note that some of these "Demo" columns don't have the same values everywhere for each ID.  For those variables, I am fine with any value for that variable.

Comment: It really depends on your data. Is it nested nested just in "ID" column (meaning you want N rows for every ID) or in multiple columns (meaning you want N rows for every combination of ID and whatever other columns)?

Comment: Hi @tmfmnk it is nested just in ID.  The change that you made to just nesting ID returns an error for me.  However, thank you so much for your guidance and pointing me to this beautiful function.  The following worked: ```DF %>% group_by(ID) %>% complete( t = seq.int(1, 5), fill = list(Attended = 0) %>% fill(Demo) %>% fill(Demo, .direction= "up") %>% arrange(ID)```.  However, because I have about 100k rows in my data the fill is taking very long for even one variable, so I will choose selectively.  If you have a suggested improvement for fill, that'd be great, but otherwise, thank you so much.

Comment: If you think that this post helped, please accept it :)